# How to remove some row in each group and keep first of them?

Tags: r, dataframe

suppose I have

```
    family   person     loop.     mode      
     1      1          1        car
     1       1         1          walk
     1       1         1         car
     1       1         2         walk
     1       1         2          bus
     1       2         1          bus
     1       2         1          walk
     1       2         2          bus
     2       1         1           car
     2       1         1           car
     2       1         2          car
     2       2        1           bus
```

I want this:

each person has some loop in each family. I want to keep the first row of each loop for each person and each family if it is car and remove all other rows in that loop (if it is car or bus or walk) . if the first row of loop is not car I don't remove anything

Output:

```
    family   person     loop.     mode      
     1      1          1          car
     1       1         2          walk
     1       1         2          bus
     1       2         1          bus
     1       2         1          walk
     1       2         2          bus
     2       1         1          car
     2       1         2          car
     2       2        1           bus
```

in the first family first person has car mode in his first row of the first loop so I removed all trips in his first loop and just kept the first one. his second loop doesn't have car mode so I kept all. second person also doesn't have car mode so I kept all. second household first person has mode car in his first loop so I kept the first row and removed rest in the loop. his second loop has one row so I kept it and second person doesn't have car mode so I kept it

Comment: it is nice to say what is the reason of your negative vote

Comment: thanks for your quick answer , it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to group by 'family', 'person', 'loop.', and `slice` only the first row `if` the `first` element of 'mode' is 'car' or else return the full number of rows

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(family, person, loop.) %>%
    slice(if(first(mode) == 'car') 1 else row_number())
# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   family, person, loop. [7]
#  family person loop. mode 
#   <int>  <int> <int> <chr>
#1      1      1     1 car  
#2      1      1     2 walk 
#3      1      1     2 bus  
#4      1      2     1 bus  
#5      1      2     1 walk 
#6      1      2     2 bus  
#7      2      1     1 car  
#8      2      1     2 car  
#9      2      2     1 bus
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(family = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), person = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L), loop. = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L), mode = c("car", "walk", "car", "walk", "bus", "bus", "walk", 
"bus", "car", "car", "car", "bus")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```